# A separate assets folder for mobiles devices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobile

I want to make my rails application mobile-friendly. There're some ways but I'm using the one where it check the user agent and passes the parameters "is_mobile" in a url and serves views from a different folder -- I don't have a different mime type for mobiles, I'm just using a different view folder and I'm fine with that.

In my `ApplicationController` I call `prepend_view_path` if a request comes from a mobile devise.

I wonder, what to do with the assets: images, js, css? Should I also create a new folder for mobile for assets -- "my_assets_for_mobile" and prepend it to the path? Something like: prepend_assets_path(....) if mobile_request? Or what?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. First step is knowing if the device requested a mobile version.

Second step is to to this: (in your `application.html.erb` layout)

```
<% if mobile? %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application-mobile', media: 'all' %>
<% else %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
<% end %>
```

Then you just have to make `application-mobile.css` manifest in your assets folder (copy and modify the `application.css`

In `application-mobile.css` you can define which assets get loaded for mobile, which ones are shared with the `application.css` and other stuff like that

Comment: and what if there're tens of them? images, fonts, etc.

Comment: Easy. Put them all in `mobile` folder. Do `require_tree 'mobile'` in the `application-mobile.css`

Comment: why not use "assets_mobile" instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) for achieving this, this is a very good tool for manging assets. You can also create page specific assets to be loaded on page. You can decide on the fly which assets to be loaded for the page based on your requirements, like mobile friendly assets or for others.

Comment: my question is yes-no, that's it, you've overcomplicated it.